# Passing some objects into a main method as arguments

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

How can i pass some existing instance objects into a main method in c #?
Or how i can initiate a reference to some existing objects (which are in another seperate runnig aplication) in my main method ?

In fact my question exactly is : how an application(main method)  can gets some objects or references to them from another running application (main method) and do some changes on them , then return them back to the first application ?
( in c# ).

Thanks for your help

Comment: *which are in another seperate runnig aplication* -- read [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335037/object-sharing-between-applications)

Comment: You can't pass anything but a string to `main`.  You can get objects a different way, though, using some form of IPC.  See [Object Sharing between Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335037/object-sharing-between-applications)

Comment: @JohnWu Technically, you can get as many strings as windows will allow :)